# Alguem sabe onde encontro esse php?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Estou procurando um arquivo, o nome dele é server-side-script.php pelo o que pesquisei parece ser um arquivo padrão de tradução, não entendi muito bem.

A questão é que tenho um script e ele vem com 2 idiomas, e pra eu acrescentar mais 1 idioma eu precisaria colocar a linha no header indicando o novo idioma e criar um arquivo para o idioma, exemplo "pt.php".

Adicionei a linha e o arquivo e ele não encontra o arquivo pt.php, é como se esse arquivo tivesse sendo setado em alguma pagina, e o action desse form indica esse arquivo server-side-script.php que eu não encontro em lugar nenhum.
Alguém sabe algo a respeito?

Div com a linha que eu precisava adicionar.

```html
            <div id="country-select">  
      <form action="server-side-script.php">
        <select id="country-options" name="country-options">
          <option <?php if($lang == 'en'){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> title="<?php echo addURLParameter($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'lang', 'en'); ?>" id="en" value="en">EN</option>
          <option <?php if($lang == 'ru'){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> title="<?php echo addURLParameter($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'lang', 'ru'); ?>" id="ru" value="ru">RU</option>
                               <option <?php if($lang == 'pt'){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> title="<?php echo addURLParameter($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'lang', 'pt'); ?>" id="pt" value="pt">PT</option>
        </select>
        <input value="Select" type="submit" />
      </form>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não tem nada a ver com o PHP em si, pois trata-se de uma questão relacionada a arquivos específicos de um sistema ou framework customizado e desconhecido, a julgar pela nomenclatura dos arquivos e estilo de código.

Consulte o desenvolvedor original ou o último responsável pelo sistema.

Comment: Ja tentei fazer isso e não encontrei o desenvolvedor original, mas de qualquer forma obrigado pelo interesse em ajudar.